# What is a one-pass algorithm, and is mine one?

Tags: java, algorithm

For a class I'm taking, it is preferred to use a `one-pass algorithm` to fix a certain task. Since this class is outside of my specialization (I'm Built Environment, the class is Computer Science), and it isn't discussed in class, I haven't got a clue what a one-pass algorithm is. Googling it gave made me think something like this:

> Each input can only be accessed once, and everything should be processed in order.

For my code below, this suggests to me that the `for loop` would fit in a `one-pass algorithm`, but I'm unsure about the `while loop`.

Could you tell me, preferably in layman's terms, what a `one-pass algorithm` means / entails, and if my code below fits this description?

```
public int[] computeDepth(int tree[]) {
    int[] depth = new int[tree.length];

    depth[0] = 0;
    for (int index=1; index < tree.length; index++) {

        depth[index] = 1;

        int parentIndex = tree[index];
        while (parentIndex != 0) {

            parentIndex = tree[parentIndex];
            depth[index]++;
        }
    }

    return depth;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Single Pass Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322007/what-is-a-single-pass-algorithm)

Comment: Have you read [the Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_algorithm)? What part confused you?

Comment: I did, and I also read the post that this would be a possible duplicate of, but for me, those explanations are quite complicated, bringing more confusion  than confirmation. I _think_ that my code would be a one-pass, but I'm not sure, because of the while loop. What confuses me is the use of (I guess) professional terms, which I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Alright. Can you provide a sample tree? I'm having trouble working out what your algorithm is expecting.

Comment: Sample input would be [0 0 0 1 2], output would be [0 1 1 2 2]. The assignment is about representing trees in arrays, this method specifically is about finding out how deep each node lies (how many lines between it and the root node)

Comment: I take it you're trying to store a **binary** tree [in this kind of manner](http://www.ad.ntust.edu.tw/course/ad5601701/lecture9.htm)?

Comment: Not completely. The tree it not binary per se, it can have more than 2 connections per node. If you replace the 'A', 'B', etc. in the table in the first image with the index of its parent's node, and the A, B, etc. in the figure with the index as stated below the table, that would be what I need. With that knowledge, the table for the first tree on that page would be [0 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154812/discussion-between-michael-and-timmiej93).

Comment: ["the algorithm doesn't need to access an item in container more than once (i.e. all of items in container are read or written only one time)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322007/what-is-a-single-pass-algorithm) - that sounds like a pretty simple explanation to me. Although I'm not sure I'd say it's a duplicate, since the question and top-voted answer focuses heavily on the C++-specific aspect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In computing, a one-pass algorithm is one which reads its input exactly once, in order, without unbounded buffering (you're not storing things elsewhere and counting that as one look). A one-pass algorithm generally requires O(n) (if you have n items, it takes n steps to finish) and less than O(n) storage (since you don't always need to use extra storage, it could be low as O(1)), where n is the size of the input.

(lifted straight from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_algorithm, with some layman translation)

A for loop is a quintessential one-pass algorithm - you look at each value exactly once and move on.  A while loop can work too, as long as it only looks at each value exactly once and does not repeat what the for loop looks at - but it's not in this case.

Your goal in this depth-first search is to look at each node exactly once, and move on, never repeating. The while loop traverses the tree multiple times, so no, it is not one-pass.

Hope that made sense.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: You can only access each input (or input array's variable in this case) once, and you can not store the input in an other, temporary variable?

Comment: Yes, no storing input somewhere else unrestrictedly. You can somewhat, but not in an unbounded fashion - if you need to store a variable in one box, that's okay, but you aren't allowed to just create more boxes for variable storage in an unlimited fashion.  An example of bounded temporary storage is, say, if I'm summing a list of numbers, the intermediary result is a bounded buffer (it only ever uses one box, and doesn't grow or shrink).  If you decide to store your entire data set in another box, that's not good, since it can be as big as your data set (it's considered unbounded).

Comment: @Kwahn `int[] depth = new int[tree.length]; ... return depth;` - this looks like the result requires `O(n)` storage anyway.

Comment: Right - if the output's O(n), you'll have to use O(n) storage.  But that's also its bound, a predefined box that's not being dynamically expanded or shrunk with no limitations.  I'm probably explaining bound vs. unbound really poorly.  Sorry :(

Comment: How does this type of algorithms (`one-pass`) relate to `online` algorithms? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm E.g.: Are `one-pass` algorithms a subset of `online` algorithms? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In layman terms, a one-pass algorithm is one which reads its input exactly once, in order.

Does your code fits the description: **No**.

You are traversing the input `tree` multiple times with the inside `while` loop:

`tree[index]` and `tree[parentIndex]`

which violates the basic criteria for the one-pass algorithm.

Comment: So basically, I can only use 1 single loop that gets each value from the `tree` array in order, and I can not access the `tree` array in any other way?

Comment: Not the same index.

Comment: How do one-pass algorithms relate to online algorithms? Quoting Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm Thank you! `An online algorithm is one that can process its input piece-by-piece in a serial fashion, i.e., in the order that the input is fed to the algorithm, without having the entire input available from the start.` This definition seems to be pretty similar to that of `one-pass` algorithms... What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix A one-pass algorithm just needs to go through each input once - an online algorithm is even more restrictive, in that the input is provided only one piece at a time, rather than providing the entire input at once.  So a loop that counts how many inputs there are, then runs that many time, wouldn't work in an online algorithm, because it doesn't receive the entire input at once, so it doesn't know how many it will receive.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I didn't understand this part though: `So a loop that counts how many inputs there are, then runs that many time, wouldn't work in an online algorithm, because it doesn't receive the entire input at once, so it doesn't know how many it will receive.` What do you mean by `runs that many time` and `wouldn't work in an online algorithm, because it doesn't receive the entire input at once, so it doesn't know how many it will receive.`? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the algorithm in OP is not one-pass as **tree** indexes are accessed multiple times(once in for and once in while). It could be converted to one-pass with something like below

```
public int[] computeDepth(int tree[]) {
    int[] depth = new int[tree.length];
    depth[0] = 0;
    for (int index=1; index < tree.length; index++) {

        depth[index] = 1;
        int parentIndex = tree[index];
        if(parentIndex != 0){
          depth[index] += depth[parentIndex]
        }
   }
   return depth;
}
```

Here we are calculating depth of child from already calculated depth of it's parent.